Black screen without anything (even cursor)
I was installing the drivers for amd gpu (unsuccesfully) and after that ubuntu loads only in recovery mode. In common mode it's just black screen, even without a cursor.
Videocard model: Radeon R7 240

You have asked a video question and have not given the make and model of the video card, the driver being used or the kernel that is running. Please edit the question and add this info, not in the comments please but by an edit.

Graphics drivers for AMD graphics are built-in, so there's no need to install anything.

This question is similar to: My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
